# For an arbitrary uncountable set of irrational numbers, can I always construct a sequence from them that converge in the rationals?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, real-numbers

Suppose you have a set $S$ of uncountably many irrational numbers. Can you construct a sequence of $S$ that converges to a rational number?

What I have tried: 
Since $S$ is uncountable, the inf of distances in this set will be arbitrarily close (otherwise if $d>0$ is a lower bound on the distance between numbers in my set then I can just inject my set into the integers by dividing the real line into intervals of length $d$, which would make $S$ countable, contradiction).

Also I can assume $S$ is bounded, since countable unions of countable sets is countable, so I can divide $S$ into intervals $S_i = S \cap [n, n+1)$. At least one of these have to be uncountable for $S$ to be countable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's possible to construct an uncountable closed set containing only irrationals. Let $\{p_n\}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$. Put $I_n = (p_n - 2^{-n-1},p_n+2^{-n-1})$. Then each $I_n$ has measure  $2^{-n}$ (if you haven't learnt Lebesgue measure before, it's just the length of $I_n$). Their union $U$ is an open set containing all rationals, but has finite measure. Hence the complement of $U$ is an uncountable closed set containing only irrationals.

Comment: Nice. (I admit I upvoted it before when it said the opposite, but this is an interesting construction of the closed set with no rationals in it. If I could upvote it again I would.)